# UIView + UIImages

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Мне нужно соединить UIView и UIImage и сделать из этого UIImage

P.S. Мне нужно сделать уникальный маркер на GoogleMap, насколько я почитал мануалы, то на карту можно ставить только UIImage *GMS_NULLABLE_PTR icon;
P.S.S Использование Info не вариант, надо сделать сразу на карте информацию, без дополнительных нажатий.

Comment: Как насчет UIImageView?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin Да, можно добавить лейбы, кнопки И так далее.... но в любов случаи его нужно будет соеденить и превратить в UIImage потому как GoogleMap не принимает UIImageView

Comment: можно как то подробнее, что надо сделать? вам надо сконвертировать UIView в UIImage? вам надо в UIView добавить UIImage как сабвью? можно как больше деталией, типа есть это и это, надо это в таком формате

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko у меня есть определенные поля, которые необходимо отображать прям на карте.

Как пример имя человека. Но без использования Info, ибо он появляется по нажатию. 

Собственно в UIView или UIImageView я добавлю нужные UILabel (addSubview) и картинку, в этом проблем нет.

Далее всю эту конструкцию необходимо конвертировать в UIImage дабы добавить в GoogleMap как маркер. marker.icon = customMarker.image

Сам этот .icon представляет собой UIImage *GMS_NULLABLE_PTR icon; И в этом заключается вся моя проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так предлагают [на англоязычном СО](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```